# SSRS Report Content types available in Central Administration but not in Sharepoint Site

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to get Sql Reporting Service running with Sharepoint server, and I have a two computer deployment, like example 2 on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677365.aspx

Site Collection Features shows Report Server Integration Feature as Active.

I now see the Reports content types available in Central Administration, but the problem is Reports Content Types are not listed at all in the Sharepoint site itself.

Why isn't the site listing the Reports Content Types?

Answer (score 1):

Did you go through the wizard in Central Admin to deploy the Reporting Services Features?

http://centraladminsite/_admin/ReportServer/ReportServerSiteSettings.aspx

Select "Activate feature in specified site collections" and choose your site collection that is giving the problems.

Also, try de-activating the Feature and re-activating.. sometimes that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with SharePoint 2016 and SQL Server 2016.
I made it work by changing the server role to "Custom" in Central Admin (System Settings -> Servers -> Convert server role in this farm)